# Why does Ubuntu hang and delete itself after fresh install?

Tags: desktop-environments, 19.04

I'm able to get to the installation, choose the partition, and complete everything just fine. But after reboot on completion, I get the loading screen and hitting ESC, I see it says, "Waiting for stop job session c2 2/1:30" while I let it do it's thing, it turns off then reboots and Ubuntu is wiped or I'll get a black screen where not even GRUB appears.

The things I've noticed is that randomly, sometimes it says "Nouveau: Unknown Chipset" and "Couldn't get size" but an error I did see until I turned off secure boot, no longer appears "Couldn't read db" or something similar.

What I've tried is booting to safemode in the installation, going to a new screen, disabling security features in my BIOS, and that's pretty much it since I can't do more.

My specs:

Ryzen 5 1600
GTX 1660 TI
512GB SSD
3200Mhz RAM
ARORUS B450 MOBO

Edit: Doing Nouveau OR Nomodeset doesn't works. It seems that the command arguments reset on install and I cannot access GRUB. I've also did "Try Ubuntu" and it sits there frozen

Comment: You need to boot with`nomodeset` then install Nvidia drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Having no internet until I could move my PC to my ethernet since it has no wifi capabilities, checking the "Download and install extra drivers" worked for sure.

An alternative was removing my GPU if I had no internet period and install the GPU drivers then install my GPU again

Thing was that GRUB wasn't even showing which I didn't understand why, but you could also if your motherboard has this option or you have an IGPU, go into your BIOS, BIOS ---> Peripherals ---> How the GPU runs or such similar option, and select On-Board Graphics or your IGPU

Answer (score 0):

For the no grub menu, I am AMD Ryzen and have an issue with grub.cfg timeout. the default is 30 seconds, and there are below that two exception handlers that are defaulted at 0 seconds. change them to a positive number - I use 10 here -  to get the grub menu to pause long enough.

```
sudo edit /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

and beware, updates will change those back again.

if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=30
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
    set timeout=10
  # Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  else
    set timeout=10
  fi